# Reading all the values except 0

Tags: php, csv

I have this module where the user first generates the blank CSV, which only contains the headers, that is six fields. Out of those 6 fields, 3 fields are filled while the other 3 are empty. 
for example: 
A, B, C, D, E, F. So the values that A, B, C contain are coming from database using the query.

Now, when user fills in D, E, F and uploads the the sheet, a problem arises. I had set this condition that whenever D & E & F are 0, it will delete that particular ID, that is A. So the particular entry with 0,0,0 will be deleted. It worked fine for a while, but now the deletion has stopped working, I don't know why. I figured out a lot, but couldn't get the solution.

Here are my code snippets.

```
$sql = "SELECT query......";
$outlet_locality_array      =   $DB->query($sql);
if(isset($outlet_locality_array[0]->minimum_order) 
    && isset($outlet_locality_array[0]->delivery_time) 
    && isset($outlet_locality_array[0]->delivery_charge))
{ 
    if(($outlet_locality_array[0]->minimum_order == 0) 
        && ($outlet_locality_array[0]->delivery_time == 0) 
        && ($outlet_locality_array[0]->delivery_charge == 0))
    {
        $condition_check = array();
        $condition_check['outlet_locality_id'] = $outlet_locality_array[0]->outlet_locality_id;

        $DB->delete(PLATFORM_OUTLET_LOCALITIES,$condition_check);

    }
}
```

Now when I tried debugging, the first IF statement executed, but the second IF statement did not execute. When I debug the variable `$outlet_locality_array`, I get all the values except the 0. And when I see the response that ajax sends, the data there shows me that the csv file that was uploaded has a 0.

So where am I missing out???

the response that i get is this:

```
csv_data:Location Id,City Name,Location Name,Minimum Order Amount,Delivery Time,Delivery Charge
5,East,Park,213,69,12123
6,East,Garden,2782,123,234
12,East,Phase 2,12345,345,2345
837,West,College,0,0,0
```

This is when I debug the array $outlet_locality_array

```
Array(    [0] => stdClass Object        (            [outlet_locality_id] => 44104            [minimum_order] => 213            [delivery_time] => 69            [delivery_charge] => 12123        ))
Array(    [0] => stdClass Object        (            [outlet_locality_id] => 44105            [minimum_order] => 2782            [delivery_time] => 123            [delivery_charge] => 234        ))
Array(    [0] => stdClass Object        (            [outlet_locality_id] => 44106            [minimum_order] => 12345            [delivery_time] => 345            [delivery_charge] => 2345        ))
```

Comment: You realise that doing a loose comparison, `"" == 0`?

Comment: Show us the data please.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Added the data. Have a look

Comment: And how do you get from the CSV file to a database? Looks to me the data is not in the database to start with.

Comment: The database still has values that needs to be deleted. And if you are asking about the query that I wrote in $sql, that is to select that particular fields from the table. So I select four fields - ID, Minimum Order, Delivery Time, Delivery Charge.